# Click a button after typing in the text fields, using the Android Chrome browser

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am trying to login on the website: https://201.247.172.70/sslvpn/Login/Login
using the latest versions of appium and chromedriver, my code is as follows:

```java
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities ();
caps.setCapability ("deviceName", "My Phone");
caps.setCapability ("udid", "4df1b558054c9fef");
caps.setCapability ("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability ("platformVersion", "4.3");
caps.setCapability ("browserName", "Chrome");
caps.setCapability ("noReset", "true");

System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C: \\ selenium_drivers \\ chromedriver.exe");
try {
driver = new AndroidDriver <MobileElement> (new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
System.out.println (e.getMessage ());
}
driver.get ("https://201.247.172.70/sslvpn/Login/Login");
driver.findElement (By.id ("userName")). sendKeys ("user");
driver.findElement (By.id ("passwordDisplayed")). sendKeys ("pass");
driver.findElement (By.id ("LoginButton")). click ();
```

When I click, it responds that it does not exist. But visually, control is observed even though it is focused on the field. Also using the UI Automator Viewer is observed.

Despite this I have tried to use the following alternatives:

Hide the keyboard after entering the text in the pass field

```java
driver.hideKeyboard ();
```

Clean the spotlights by means of JS

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor3.executeScript ("document.activeElement.blur ();");
```

Change the site zoom to "force" to see the control.

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor2.executeScript ("document.body.style.zoom = '50% ';");
```

Print the code to validate that there is

```java
System.out.println (driver2.getPageSource ());
Where the button is observed:
<! - Submit button ->
<tr>
<td id = "LoginButtonTD" align = "right">
<div id = "submitDiv">
<input type = "submit" id = "LoginButton" name = "Login" value = "Sign In" align = "absmiddle" class = "butt" />
</ div>
</ td>
</ tr> <! - submit button ->
```

I have also used the following sentence

```java
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@text,'Sign In')]").click();
```

Although control exists, it does not take it.

Using the pc browser works without problems, but I need it from the mobile browser (Android).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DStF.jpg)

Comment: I doubt whether this is the case that the element presence but not yet shown in the vision.

Comment: @jadcode Did you try to locate the element using text "Sign In" ? Also Can you add the screen shot of Ui Automator View of the screen?

Comment: @Vinod,  I used this sentence: driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@text,'Sign In')]").click(); Screen shot https://photos.app.goo.gl/iKWfzjySjnRhu1xr5

Comment: It looks like you're mixing native and web contexts without ever switching between them.

Comment: @Jadcode Which android version are you using for testing this application?

Comment: @Vinod. Android 4.4.2 (galaxy note II).

It works sending the action by js

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript ("document.getElementById (\" LoginButton \ "). click ();");

But sending it directly does not work, I think it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

4.4.2 is very old version of Android. If you are using any version which is lower than 6.0, then you need to switch to WEBVIEW and perform the actions.

If you are using 6.0 or higher version then you don't need to switch to WEBVIEW, Android UiAutomator takes care of it.